# How to split string with multiple semi colons javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, split

I have a string like below

`var exampleString = "Name:Sivakumar ; Tadisetti;Country:India"`

I want to split above string with semi colon, so want the array like

`var result = [ "Name:Sivakumar ; Tadisetti", "Country:India" ]`

But as the name contains another semi colon, I am getting array like

`var result = [ "Name:Sivakumar ", "Tadisetti", "Country:India" ]`

Here `Sivakumar ; Tadisetti` value of the key `Name`

I just wrote the code like `exampleString.split(';')`... other than this not able to get an idea to proceed further to get my desired output. Any suggestions?

**Logic to split**: I want to split the string as array with `key:value` pairs

Comment: What is the logic that defines which `;` to split at ? There are 2 semi-colons in your string.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I want to split the string with key:value pairs

Comment: @Leonardo No "Sivakumar ; Tadisetti" is a single value

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli `key` doesn't contains semicolons, but `value` may contain more than one semicolon ex: `Name:Sivakumar ; Tadisetti`, `Country:India`

Comment: Does a value always end with a semicolon?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli yes it always end with a semicolon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.split` accepts regular expressions as well, you can use a one that matches semicolons that are only followed by alphanumeric characters that end in `:` (*in effect if they are followed by another key*)

[`/;(?=\w+:)/`](https://regex101.com/r/YKnre9/1)

```js
var exampleString = "Name:Sivakumar ; Tadisetti;Country:India";
var result = exampleString.split(/;(?=\w+:)/);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: dude; nice and clean.

Answer (score 1):

here is an approach which we first split the input on `;` and then concat the element without `:` with the previous one; since it shouldn't being spited.

```js
let exampleString = "Name:Sivakumar ; Tadisetti;Country:India"
let reverseSplited = exampleString.split(";").reverse();

let prevoiusString;
let regex = /[^:]+:.*/;

let result = reverseSplited.map( str => {
  if(regex.test(str)) {
    if(prevoiusString){
     let returnValue = str + ";" + prevoiusString;
     prevoiusString = null;
     return returnValue
    }
    return str
  }
  prevoiusString = str;
}).filter(e=>e);


console.log(result);
```